# Kafka stream with sub topologies, why the number of patitions is always 100?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream process that should process messages from topic: "DATABASES" that contains massages from ~10 different databases.

After I start streaming, I select the databaseID as a key and send to processor with store for doing some logic.

Then I put the messages to another topic: "DB_FOR_MONITORING_TOPIC".

When I try run it, it take a lot of time and doesn't succeded to finish.

It looks like a lot of steps are done for 100 different tasks.

Also when I run: kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic db_for_monitoring

I see that this topic has 100 partitions.

I missunderstand it, as soon as I read the topic can be partitioned by key.

So the number of partitions should be dynamic according to the number of messages type, Isn't it?

here is my code:

```
 StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Database>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
              Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(DB_INFO_STORE), 
                  Serdes.String(),databaseSerde).withLoggingDisabled();

    
    builder
    .addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder)
    .stream(DATABASES_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), databaseSerde))
    .selectKey((id , db) -> db.getId())  // todo: to remove after we sure the databases topic is partitioned by DBId
    .process(new ProcessorSupplier() {
         public Processor get() {
             return new ScheduleMonitoringProcessor();
         }
     }
    ,DB_INFO_STORE
    ).to(DB_FOR_MONITORING_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), MonitoredSessionEntitySerde));
```

and the logs:

[image]

Comment: How many partitions for the topic DATABASES_TOPIC?

Comment: 100, so is it stayed with the same number of partiotions all the time? also after selectKey?

Comment: Kafka Streams has no clue about the cardinality of your keys (the number of different keys in a topic, often unbounded) and selectKey has no intelligence/memory about that either. You could create your topic DB_FOR_MONITORING_TOPIC manually before (let's say 10 partitions).

Comment: The number of partitions of a topic doesn't depend on data in the topic. It's defined during the topic's creation